# Can a person marry his wife a second time without a divorce?

Tags: nikah, fiqh, talaq

A boy and girl who knew each other through an educational institute got married to avoid zina without informing their parents. Now if at a later stage, their parents find out and want them to get '***officially married ***' after completing their education, will this '***second nikkah***' be considered a sin as they are already married to each other.

**Original Question asked by OP in Urdu/Hindi:**

> Ager koi larka aur larki ik dosre ko pasand karte ho aur wo  ek dosre
>   se baat krte ho aur sath rehte ho institute mai .call pe bhe baat krte
>   ho aur unko pata ho k ye gunnah hai aur wo nikkah  krle ghar walo ko
>   btae bgair takey wo koi gunnah na kre .. mager unki family undono ka
>   nikkah baad mai prhae khatm hone kay baad krwae aik dosre k sath
>   dobara se..  tw kia wo nikkah jaiz hoga uska koi gunnah tw nahi hoga?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an English-only site.

Comment: This question lacks details: Is all what they have done not informing the parents of the girl, or both parents or only the parents of the boy. Were there for the first nikah  two witnesses and the guardian of the girl or whom? If these points are clarified we may move to try to answer the question.